# High, Fluctuating '% Time in JIT' on Precompiled ASP.NET Website

Tags: c#, asp.net, compiler-construction, performance, jit

With a 150 *.dll ASP.NET website that's **precompiled** (updatable), what are some possible causes for a '**% Time in JIT**' that is often quite high (> 60%) and **fluctuating** long after the application has warmed-up (all functionality accessed) and without 
app restarts or file changes that might generate new assemblies?

One would expect that the machine code generated for *all* assemblies would be re-used for the duration of that app-domain. Is there a finite size to the volume of machine-code that's cached? Under what scenarios would the same assembly need to be re-JIT'd in the same app domain? Or is it necessarily the case that new assemblies are being generated? Do factors such as memory pressure impact this performance counter?

**Reference**:

- http://forums.asp.net/p/967386/2959500.aspx

Comment: regular expressions generate assemblies behind the scenes, if these are constantly re-created that could be a contributing factor...

Answer (score 1):

It could be anything that does assembly emit. Linq Expressions compile, or regular expressions, that are not being cached correctly.

Comment: Indeed. You have to be /really/ careful with regular expressions: sometimes they can leak. See http://www.informit.com/guides/content.aspx?g=dotnet&seqNum=692 for examples of how to pre-compile and cache them.

Answer (score 0):

If you are setting cache parameters, you may be inadvertently disabling the precompiled server-side cache. Take a look at this article:

http://codeclimber.net.nz/archive/2007/04/01/Beware-the-ASP.NET-SetCacheability-method.aspx