# Speeding up load times for an ASP.Net website

Tags: asp.net, performance, webforms

We have an ASP.Net Webforms site (.Net 3.5) that has about 100 references in the project, so it's not tiny.  Reuilding the site takes maybe 20-30 seconds but it's the load time that's a killer.  At least 5 minutes before the first page opens in the browser on our development machines.  We're building in VS 2012 fwiw.

What can we do to speed things up?  There's an 'optimizeCompilation' flag you can put into web.config, and that's helped a little but not as much as we'd hoped.  Is there a checklist we can go through to try and find the real bottlenecks in the site load time?

I can state that when the site is coming up the ASP.Net Temporary files folder slowly accumulates files.  When all is said and done there are about 2500 files in there, ~70MB total size.  It almost feels like we can hand-write the contents of that folder using Notepad faster than ASP.Net puts them in there.

Comment: http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html

Answer (score 2):

What difference do you get if you change from Debug to Release ?

Also, have a look at native image generation:

[Does it help to use NGEN?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/385841/does-it-help-to-use-ngen)

Lastly, 100 references seems excessive! What are you doing with them? Is it your own code? Can you consolidate your own code into single projects ?
Do some of these references themselves reference web services or anything like that ?

Comment: We'll try the debug vs release change, and look at NGEN.  Unfortunately we need to debug the site so keeping that flag to release won't be a permanent fix, but it will help to at least see the effects.
I agree, 100 references is a lot, and we're trying to consolidate via NuGet packages.  The site itself is ~ 100 ascx controls and 25 aspx pages.