# Dynamically compiled website - compile to the fullest on startup?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, msbuild, web

I have an ASP.NET website and it compiles on the fly, except I think it is JIT-compiled. Is there any compile options that I can put so that it would compile to the fullest before actually running?

Converting to web application (ie the ones with single DLL that statically compile) is an option, although I still want it to be dynamically compiled. I think there has to be some place where I could insert a flag telling the compiler to not do anything until fully compiled.

Another solution would be precompiling, though I am not sure how to do that yet.

One problem with JIT-compiled is that I need to warm it up (manually). Also, I do not know what MS did, but when I actually want to build it with `MSBuild` (instead of the runtime compiler which I think is responsible for JIT-compiling), it is very very slow for some reason, and it recompiles everything even if I didnt change it.

Comment: I can't quite understand what you're looking for here. Maybe you're thinking of `ngen`, but I don't think that'll be much help to you unless startup times are you prime concern. See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/385841/does-it-help-to-use-ngen