# IIS still runs csc.exe after aspnet_compiler has been used to compile application

Tags: asp.net, iis, csc, aspnet-compiler

I've been trying to use aspnet_compiler to pre-compile my asp.net site in order to avoid or minimize running csc.exe after an application pool recycle. However after running the compiler recycling the app pool still causes a tonne of csc.exe processes to be kicked off and the server to grind to a halt until compilation is complete.

The command I'm running to compile the site is:
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_compiler.exe -p "E:\webRoot\application" -v //localhost/application E:\webRoot\application

I've scoured the internet for an answer to this but I haven't managed to turn up much. If anyone has any suggestions they would be greatly appreciated as this is causing severe performance problems for all sites running on the server that the application pool recycle occurs on.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: have you tried to use NGEN? http://stackoverflow.com/a/385851/559144